# How to sign-in to Google without Signing-in to Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, privacy

I don't use the Chrome user account features and don't want the browser to know my Google account. In the past I just didn't sign-in to Chrome, signed-in to Google (mostly to sign-in to StackEchange with my Google account) and it seemed Ok. But now as I've updated to Chrome 69 it signs me in to Chrome every time I sign-in to StackExchange with my Google account. Can this behavior be disabled?

Comment: chrome://flags/#account-consistency & change to Disabled. This is guess based on https://lifehacker.com/how-to-turn-off-the-auto-sign-out-link-in-gmail-and-chr-1828953840 . I guess someone in comments said solution to your request is to disable cookies for youtube/google. However I feel like thats not a proper solution. I'm curious how this will pan out. In the mean time use Incognito Window?

Answer (score 5):

As you noticed, starting with Chrome 69, this “auto sign-in” feature was added. It automatically signs you into Chrome when you sign into a Google website or use a Google account to sign into other websites (e.g., Stack Exchange).

This feature was frustrating for many users and since Chrome 70, users can disable it:

**Open settings** and search for "sign-in".

[image]

**Disable "Allow Chrome sign-in".**

To apply this change, **relaunch** Chrome